# Dynamics 365 Team license alternative

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Recently Microsoft announced some changes to their Dynamics 365 Teams license. The people who have these licenses will not be able to access Sales Hub, Marketing Hub, custom model driven apps etc and will have their own app like Sales Team member app.

These dedicated apps have restrictions of only 15 custom entities.

This change will cause some of our clients a lot of problems. As per my understanding, the only option they will have is to buy the full Dynamics license.

Am I correct on above? If no then feel free to correct me. If yes then can anyone suggest a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the new licensing model is quite confusing.
I suggest to check the updated licensing guide (if not already done)
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=866544

(if the link does not work, it is taken from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365-release-plan/2020wave1/dynamics365-sales/license-enforcement-users-new-team-member-licenses)

Allthough this document is quite extensive, it is also recommended to talk with you MS Sales Rep (or anyone else who is responsible for you from MS side) to make sure all your needs are covered.

Comment: Do we have any impact on Dynamics app for outlook?

Comment: According to this blog entry https://www.mindsunited.com/blog/2020/01/28/license-enforcement-coming-to-dynamics-365-team-member-licenses-in-april-2020-a-k-a-good-bye-team-member, we can create a model driven app and give access rights to users with powerapp plan but I found that to access Dynamics 365 entities, we need Dynamics license. Can someone please confirm this?

Comment: @InkeySolutions That's correct. To access Dyn365 entities you need to have a Team Member licence (which includes 15 custom entities)